# Not able to make setting value to "innerHTML" for an element work

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm newbie to JS. I've a code sample below, in which I've written a JS function through which I'm trying to change value of <**p**> tag after a button click. My question is why only setting **innerHTML** work with 'getElementById()'; but not with the other approaches?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myid").innerHTML = 'hey';
    document.getElementByName("myname").innerHTML = 'Whats';
    document.getElementByTagName("p").innerHTML = 'up! ';
    document.querySelector("p#myid").innerHTML = 'Dude.';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="myid" name="myname">This text will be changed after button click.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**Result:** I was Expecting "Dude." displayed after the click.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: Why did you edit your question with the solution?

Comment: Thanks for reverting back!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change as follows, it works

```
document.getElementById("myid").innerHTML = 'hey';  
document.getElementsByName("myname")[0].innerHTML = 'Whats'; 
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = 'up! ';
document.querySelector("p#myid").innerHTML = 'Dude.';
```

Comment: Will mark this one as accepted, because this addresses the problem; although without explaining it.

Comment: getElementsByName(), getElementsByTagName() are the methods not as getElementByName(), getElementByTagName().

Answer (score 4):

The script fails on the `document.getElementByName("myname").innerHTML = 'Whats';` line, because `getElementByName` is not a function, and it errors when the script tries to call it. The correct name is [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName); element**s**. Same for [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName).

Also, both functions return lists of elements and not single elements. Because of that, here, you want to use `[0]` to get the first element in that list, then work with it that way:

```
document.getElementsByName("myname")[0].innerHTML = 'Whats';
```

Use <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (depending on the browser) to open up your browser console to see errors, and consult the documentation (from the site I linked for example) to make sure you're using the right function.

Comment: Okay thanks, what if I use document.getElementsByName("myname")[0], I've changed it in my question?

Comment: Thanks got what I was looking for

Comment: Sure, happy to help c: In the future, however, I'd recommend against editing your question with the solution; that's what the answers are for.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
 debugger;
    document.getElementById("myid").innerHTML = 'hey';
    document.getElementsByName("myname").innerHTML = 'Whats';
    document.getElementsByTagName("p").innerHTML = 'up! ';
    document.querySelector("p#myid").innerHTML = 'Dude.';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="myid" name="myname">This text will be changed after button click.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Here you have wrote document.getElementByName("myname").innerHTML = 'Whats';
which is not correct it must be document.getElementsByName("myname").innerHTML = 'Whats'; Try this It works.
FYI document.getElementsByName return array of elements with same name .

Comment: This `document.getElementsByName("myname").innerHTML`  is only creating an attribute `innerHTML` into the returned NodeList. Not ok!

Comment: but here script throw error on document.getElementByName("myname").innerHTML = 'Whats'; and rest of script is not executed

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure `document.querySelectorAll`, `document.getElementsByClassName` and `document.getElementsByTagName` will return a NodeList object. However, `document.querySelector` should return the first match of that element within the given context (document).